# Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subset C$, then $A \subset C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subset C$, then $A \subset C$.

---

Proof:

$A \subseteq B \Longrightarrow \forall x\in A, x \in B.$ Since $B \subset C$, it follows that $x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in C$ but $\exists c \in C \ni c \notin B.$
Since $A \subseteq B$, it follows that $c \notin A$, thus $A \subset C$.

---

Is this good enough?

Comment: You may want to add "$x\in A\implies x\in B \implies x\in C$, so $A\subseteq C$" somewhere in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't understand why people downvote your question...
Your proof works but is not really clear. You should break it into two part :

$A \subseteq B \Longrightarrow \forall x\in A, x \in B.$ Since $B \subset C$, it follows that $x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in C$. Thus $\forall x \in A$, $x \in C$, thus $A \subseteq C$.

Or $B \subset C \Longrightarrow \exists c \in C$ and $c \notin B.$
Since $A \subseteq B$, it follows that $c \notin A$, thus $A \subset C$.

Answer (score 0):

If A is a subset B then for all A is element of B. It follows B is a subset of C for all B is element of C. Since A is element of B for all A and B is element of C for all B Therefore A is subset of C.